# Springboot custom autoconfiguration in Gradle not loading

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-starter, spring-autoconfiguration

So I have I built a custom Springboot starter and autoconfiguration and everything builds fine, the code is all their in the local maven repo.

I even checked the generated jars and everything looksgood.

Can't load the generated files into the project but when I look at the generated beens, there is no sign of beans created by autoconfiguration (or the autoconfiguration itself) : https://github.com/orubel/spring-boot-starter-beapi/issues/37

Project code can be sen here: https://github.com/orubel/spring-boot-starter-beapi/blob/main/beapi-lib/build.gradle

what am I doing wrong that implementations can';t see the beans?

I have tried bringing in the dependencies from mavenLocal() with:

implementation "io.beapi:beapi-lib:0.4"
implementation "io.beapi:beapi-spring-boot-starter:0.4"

and with:

implementation "io.beapi:beapi-lib:0.4"
implementation "io.beapi:beapi-spring-boot-autoconfigure:0.4"

Both have the same error of stating that an AUTOWIRED bean (from the autoconfiguration) cannot be found:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'io.beapi.lib.service.PrincipleService' in your configuration.
```

If I comment out the autowired bean, it just throws error that bean is null.

Answer (score -1):

Ok solved my issue.

As I am instantiating the beans from a library I am creating through the starter, I have to do a '@ComponentScan' on those classes.

So just adding:

```
@ComponentScan(["io.beapi.lib.service"])
```

To the application main class was enough to resolve this :)